# Why is my dependent drop down disappearing upon submission?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a form with a dependent drop down. Whenever the form is submitted, only the first field is cleared, if the drop downs were filled out, they remain the same. I have the dependent dropdown set to appear only when there are options available, but after the form gets submitted with an option that has a secondary option, only the first dropdown renders, because it does not load the dropdown logic until you select a new option and go back to what you had. For a more visual understanding:

This is the form when the page first loads

[image]

When you select an option that has secondary options, the other dropdown appears

[image]

After you select a Station and submit, the Employee # clears, but the other two remain, however, when the page reloads upon submission, it looks like this

[image]

And when I look at the data that remained in the form, only the work area stayed, because the dependent dropdown does not load until you select another option from the drop down, and if you wanted to be able to see the Box Assembly options again, you'd have to click another option and then go back to Box Assembly (for example)

How could I fix this issue? Is there a way to force the javascript to attempt to render first, whether it has been triggered or not?

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['station_number'].queryset = Station.objects.none()

        if 'work_area' in self.data:
            try:
                work_area_id = int(self.data.get('work_area'))
                self.fields['station_number'].queryset = Station.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['station_number'].queryset = self.instance.work_area.stations.order_by('name')
```

**views.py**

```
def enter_exit_area(request):
    enter_without_exit = None
    exit_without_enter = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WarehouseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            emp_num = form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
            area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
            station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']

            if 'enter_area' in request.POST:
                new_entry = form.save()
                EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter((Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(work_area=area) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_in__isnull=True)) & (Q(station_number=station) | Q(station_number__isnull=True))).update(time_in=datetime.now())

                # If employee has an entry without an exit and attempts to enter a new area, mark as an exception 'needs_approval'
                enters_without_exits = EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_exceptions="")).exclude(pk=new_entry.pk).order_by("-time_in")
                if len(enters_without_exits) > 0:
                    enter_without_exit = enters_without_exits[0]
                    enters_without_exits.update(time_exceptions='needs_approval')

                message = 'You have entered %(area)s' % {'area': area}
                if station is not None:
                    message += ': %(station)s' % {'station': station}
                messages.success(request, message)
                form = WarehouseForm(initial={'employee_number': '', 'work_area': area, 'station_number': station})

            elif 'leave_area' in request.POST:
                if EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(employee_number=emp_num, work_area=area, station_number=station, time_out__isnull=True, time_exceptions=""):
                    recent = EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(employee_number=emp_num, work_area=area, station_number=station, time_out__isnull=True).latest('time_in').time_in
                    EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(employee_number=emp_num, work_area=area, station_number=station, time_out__isnull=True, time_in=recent, time_exceptions="").update(time_out=datetime.now())
                else:
                    exit_without_enter = form.save()
                    EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(employee_number=emp_num, work_area=area, station_number=station, time_in__isnull=True, time_exceptions="").update(time_exceptions='needs_approval', time_out=datetime.now())

                message = 'You have exited %(area)s' % {'area': area}
                if station is not None:
                    message += ': %(station)s' % {'station': station}
                messages.success(request, message)
                form = WarehouseForm(initial={'employee_number': '', 'work_area': area, 'station_number': station})
    else:
        form = WarehouseForm()
    return render(request, "operations/enter_exit_area.html", {
        'form': form,
        'enter_without_exit': enter_without_exit,
        'exit_without_enter': exit_without_enter,
    })

def load_stations(request):
    work_area_id = request.GET.get('work_area')
    stations = Station.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'operations/station_number_dropdown_options.html', {'stations': stations})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', views.enter_exit_area, name='enter_exit_area'),

    path('ajax/load-stations/', views.load_stations, name='ajax_load_stations'),
]
```

At the end of this html is the script that handles the dependent dropdown

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "operations/base.html" %}
{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" data-stations-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_load_stations' %}" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div>
            <div>
                <label>Employee #</label>
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Work Area</label>
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8" id="my-hidden-div">
                <label>Station</label>
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $("#id_work_area").change(function () {
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr("data-stations-url");
            var workAreaId = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'work_area': workAreaId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#my-hidden-div").show(); // show it
                    $("#id_station_number").html(data);
                    // Check the length of the options child elements of the select
                    if ($("#id_station_number option").length == 1) {
                        $("#id_station_number").parent().hide(); // Hide parent of the select node
                    } else {
                        // If any option, ensure the select is shown
                        $("#id_station_number").parent().show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
     </script>
{% endblock main %}
```

**station_number_dropdown_options.html**

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for station in stations %}
<option value="{{ station.pk }}">{{ station.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What do you want? The WorkArea dropdown should clear (in which case you need to show us the form handling view because the value comes from there)? Or you want the second drop down to be there because there's a selection for WorkArea?

Comment: The Work Area and Station should not clear if the user had selected an option for both when they filled out and submitted the form, however, the Station is clearing and disappearing. And when the page reloads after submission, the work area is selected, yet the station options aren't showing, even though "Box Assembly" does have options to pick from, the url is just not called since it is set to be triggered when a "new" options is selected, hence why I have to select a different option and go back to Box Assembly to be able to see them again. Adding the form handling just in case.

Comment: Then you need to call the same js logic when the document is ready (or window loads: `$(window).on('load', function() {...})`). Wrap your js in a separate function and call that function both on change and on window load. You'll need to pass the element as a parameter to that function.

Comment: How can I pass the data to the function? Not very familiar with JS, that part of my code comes from a tutorial on dependent dropdowns

Comment: just define `function myFunction(param) { ... }` and call it with `myFunction(someParam)`.